# Data rows, variables and values get reordered during computations

Tags: r

I have a problem with R when adding my data to a matrix prior to drawing:

```
> resFile <- read.csv("file.csv")
> print(resFile)
     Gene Virus  Expression    Percentage
1    ga   1Virus 2.738598e-02  38.590745
2    ga   2Virus 3.247252e-02  64.331929
3    ga   PIC    4.235604e-02  114.348940
4    ga   MOCK   1.976032e-02  0.000000        
> samples <- unique(resFile$Virus)
> genes <- unique(resFile$Gene)
> numGene <- length(genes)
> numSmpl <- length(samples)

> mat <- matrix(ncol=numGene,nrow=numSmpl,dimnames=list(samples,genes))
> mat[samples,genes]<-resFile$Percentage
> print(mat)
              ga 
1Virus  38.59074
2Virus  64.33193
PIC      0.00000
MOCK   114.34894
```

As you can see, the `percentage` values are switched between my PIC and MOCK samples. This happens to whole columns as well and it looks like the values are added in alphabetical order instead of indicially.

Why is this happening and how can I get around it?

Comment: What are `samples` and `genes`?

Comment: They are simply vectors that are used to generate headers for the matrix.

Comment: How is `samples` ordered?

Comment: Samples are ordered according to @Miff's answer! I updated my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post reproducible code (use `dput()`). As Miff says, lines like `samples <- unique(resFile$Virus)` is giving you unwanted reordering. But we need to see the actual rownames and levels.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, 1Virus,2Virus,PIC,MOCK are out of alphabetical order, and the reason you got that is from the irritating default `read.csv()` `default.stringsAsFactors() = T`. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here with the line:

```
mat[samples,genes] <- resFile$Percentage
```

Firstly, if `samples` and `genes` are taken from resFile, they'll probably be factors rather than strings, so if the order of `samples` or `genes` differs from the order of the factor levels you'll get the rows or columns shuffled.

Secondly, this assigns the `resFile$Percentage` to all the subset of `mat` where the row name is in `samples` and the column name in `genes`, rather than taking them pairwise.

To get round these problems, try the following (I'm making assumptions about how you generated `samples` and `genes`:

```
resFile <- data.frame(Gene="ga",
                      Virus=c("1Virus","2Virus","PIC","MOCK"),          
                      Percentage=c(38.59,64.33,114.34,0))
samples <- unique(resFile$Virus)
genes <- unique(resFile$Gene)
numGene <- length(genes)
numSmpl <- length(samples)
mat <- matrix(ncol=numGene,nrow=numSmpl,dimnames=list(samples,genes))

mat[cbind(as.character(resFile$Virus)),as.character(resFile$Gene)] <- resFile$Percentage
mat
#            ga
# 1Virus  38.59
# 2Virus  64.33
# PIC    114.34
# MOCK     0.00
```

The key differences are that I've converted the factor variables to character, and indexed using a matrix rather than two vectors - see `?'['` for a better explanation of indexing by arrays than I can manage.

Comment: Thank you! The `as.character()` did the trick. Didn't need the `cbind()` though.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever got the weirdness because **you read in the CSV with the irritating default `stringsAsFactors() = TRUE`**. Hence all your string columns become factors, and moreover they use the default `factor(..., ordered=F)`. You could read them in as strings, then convert to `factor(..., ordered=T)` if you liked.

Then, whenever you see someone construct a matrix/vector from `unique(df$factorCol)`, as opposed to `labels()`, you revisit that ordering issue, unless the factor is ordered.

In your case **you don't even need to create a matrix, you could get your x,y-series directly from a dataframe slice `resFile[, c('Virus','Percentage')]`**

```
resFile <- read.csv("res.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)

resFile[, c('Virus','Percentage')]
   Virus Percentage
1 1Virus   38.59074
2 2Virus   64.33193
3    PIC  114.34894
4   MOCK    0.00000

> as.matrix(resFile[, c('Virus','Percentage')])
     Virus    Percentage 
[1,] "1Virus" " 38.59074"
[2,] "2Virus" " 64.33193"
[3,] "PIC"    "114.34894"
[4,] "MOCK"   "  0.00000"
# Creating a matrix from slices of dataframe isn't desirable, not just for the row-ordering, but also because all entries are coerced to string. So just don't do it.
```

Now if you wanted in general to get a group for each Gene, then select just the Virus, Percentage columns, use dplyr:

```
> require(dplyr)
> ga_slice <- resFile %>% group_by(Gene) %>% select(Virus,Percentage) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-Gene)
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

   Virus Percentage
1 1Virus   38.59074
2 2Virus   64.33193
3    PIC  114.34894
4   MOCK    0.00000
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `stringsAsFactors` argument `TRUE` default actually and adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` also solves my problem. Oh, and in my case I actually need to create a matrix as the question is just a small part of my full code, but thanks anyway.